# Jquery delay background animation not working

Tags: jquery

I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
$('#myDiv').css('background', 'url("Img/image.gif")').delay(500).css('background', 'none');
```

I want #myDiv to have a background and it be removed after 500ms.

Can anyone help on this please?

Comment: can you provide some more code? it would be more helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`css` is not an animation, therefore delay does not affect it.

Use `setTimeout` instead:

```
var $div = $('#myDiv').css('background', 'url("Img/image.gif")');

setTimeout(function(){
    $div.css('background', 'none');
}, 500);
```

Comment: But it seems jQuery doc shows it in just that way: http://api.jquery.com/delay/ (see the examples section)

Comment: "Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue."   `css` is not in the queue because it is not an animation.

Answer (score 0):

Just a typo. I think you have missed the `#` part:

```
$('#myDiv')
```

It should be and id/class selector; otherwise jQuery will look for a tag named `myDiv`.

By the way, I think James Montagne addresses the real problem above.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `delay()` works with animations and also we cannot animate between bitmap data like images try using `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` instead to create the fading background effect.